# Inner Joins with where clause in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, select, join, inner-join, where-clause

I have tried all answers but none are working. But the code is working when I use only one column either State or LGA. When I combine the two as you can find in the query below I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Please help me out

Code:

```
SELECT [Community].[CommunityID], 
       [Community].[CommunityName], 
       [Community].[StateID], 
       [StateName] AS [StateName], 
       [Community.LGAID], 
       [LGA].[LGName] AS [LGName] 
FROM [Community], [State] 
WHERE ([Community].[StateID] = [State].[StateID], [LGA] 
WHERE [Community].[LGAID] = [LGA].[LGAID]
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do join and it is syntax error near to LGA, you can convert your code as below to provide explicit join conditions

```
SELECT [Community].[CommunityID], [Community].[CommunityName], [Community].[StateID], [StateName] AS [StateName], [Community].[LGAID], [LGA].[LGName] AS [LGName] 
FROM [Community] JOIN [State] ON [Community].[StateID] = [State].[StateID]
JOIN [LGA] ON [Community].[LGAID]=[LGA].[LGAID]
```

Comment: [Community.LGAID] changed to [Community].[LGAID]. Thank you Kannan. Is working now!!!